# Category history

Tags: c#

I have two classes in this project;

**Category:** This will be responsible to hold the latest information.

```
public class Om_Category
{
    public Int32 CategoryID { get; set; }
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    public String CategorySanitized { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Int32 ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public Int64 CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Int64 ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

**Category History:** This will hold the history of all modifications done for any category.

```
public class Om_CategoryHistory
{
    public Int32 CategoryID { get; set; }
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    public String CategorySanitized { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModificationDate { get; set; }
    public Int64 LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anything that I can reuse or optimizations I can make?

Comment: Any specific reason for the `Om_` in the title of the classes, doesn't server any purpose in my opinion.

Comment: Om stands for Object Model. So in this scenario it is Om_Category. I saw in many files, people like to say Business Entities. So it becomes BE_Category

Comment: Then can't you create a *namespace* to separate the entities?

Comment: see my below answer for a bigger explanation.

Comment: Shouldn't you change `IsActive` to `WasActive`?  Also, while it's clear that any property of `Om_Category` may be changed, can we assume that the properties of an `Om_CategoryHistory` instance will never be changed after creation?  (Wouldn't be much of a history if it could be arbitrarily modified)

Comment: Final question: how much scope do you have to change anything?  Are there constraints set by the tutor (if this is a course project) or by the rest of the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the common for both properties to a base class which both classes then inherit like so

```
public class Om_CategoryBase
{
    public Int32 CategoryID { get; set; }
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    public String CategorySanitized { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModificationDate { get; set; }
    public Int64 LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Om_Category : Om_CategoryBase
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Om_CategoryHistory : Om_CategoryBase
{

}
```

but you should maybe come up with a better name.

If the property setters don't have to be `public` you should consider to make them `protected` instead.

Based on the comment

> Kindly explain with the help of an example for this :If the property setters don't have to be public you should consider to make them protected instead.

Like `public` and `private` the `protected` scope defines in which scope a method or property can be accessed. `Protected` means it can be accessed by the class itself and the class which is inheriting from this class.

For instance if you would make the  setter of `CategoryID` protected like so

```
public class Om_CategoryBase
{
    public Int32 CategoryID { get; protected set; }
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    public String CategorySanitized { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModificationDate { get; set; }
    public Int64 LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

you can only set this property from within this base class and from inside the derived classes `Om_Category` and `Om_CategoryHistory`. If you would try to set this property from another class which doesn't inherit the base class, your IDE would show an error.

So assuming the `Om_Category` would have a constructor like so

```
public Om_Category (int catagoryId)
{
    CategoryID = categoryId;
}
```

the `CategoryID` property would be set to the passed in `categoryId` value.

Comment: Very good answer (as usual)! One little question: am I wrong or is in the last example *CategoryID* still `public`?

Comment: @Abbas no, the setter is `protected` see the second last code block.

Comment: Somehow I knew I had to leave your answer and don't just edit it, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Why a base class and not an interface?

Comment: @itsbruce because here it wouldn't really help IMHO. The op asks for reuse so its either needs to be base class with inheritance or interface with composition where I choose the former because the op seems to be a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

The [**answer of Heslacher**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105982/22020) covers the most important part. This answer is intended as a reply to the comments, regarding the use of a `namespace`. Here's the definition of the namespace keyword (from [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/z2kcy19k.aspx)):

> The **namespace** keyword is used to declare a scope that contains a set of related objects. You can use a namespace to organize code elements and to create globally unique types.

A simple example:

```
System.Console.Write("Hello world!");
```

In above code:

- `System` is the **namespace**
- `Console` is a class
- `Write` is a method

There are many classes in the `System` namespace. Namespaces can also be nested, for example the `System.Data` namespace, it contains several classes for the ADO.NET architecture in .NET.

Deeply nested namespaces will result in longer code. For example:

```
namespace Services
{
    namespace Management
    {
        namespace Data
        {
            class MyClass
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime you want to instantiate a class in the `Data` namespace you'd have to write:

```
Services.Management.Data.MyClass myClass = new Services.Management.Data.MyClass();
```

You have two options:

- use the `using` statement:

  ```
  using Services.Management.Data;

  MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
  ```
- use an alias:

  ```
  using data = Services.Management.Data;

  data.MyClass = new data.MyClass();
  ```

More reading on namespaces:

- [**Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx)
- [**Using Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s(v=vs.140).aspx)

Now you know what you can do with namespaces, you can apply it to your code:

```
namespace ObjectModel
{
    public class Category { }
}

namespace BusinessEntities
{
    public class Category { }
}

var omCat = new ObjectModel.Category();
var beCat = new BusinessEntities.Category();
```

As I said, your main question is resolved by the answer of Heslacher but I hope this answer is of any help.